# How to Create a Trajectory for a Tracked Vehicle Model in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

I am currently working on a tracked vehicle model in Matlab Simulink that needs to follow a trajectory while considering ground parameters. I have referred to a specific paper that outlines the dynamic and kinematic models for the vehicle.

Now I am trying to implement a trajectory for the vehicle to follow using Simulink. Specifically, I would like to create a trajectory by defining waypoints that the vehicle should pass through. However, I am unsure how to proceed with this implementation.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to integrate these dynamic and kinematic equations into Simulink to create a trajectory? Additionally, how can I define waypoints and adjust the vehicle's speeds accordingly based on the given equations?

Equations extracted from the Paper:

**Dynamic Model**

```
m*x'' = Fi + Fo - Ri - Ro

m*y'' = 4 * fy * d

IG * psi'' = (Fo - Ro) * b - (Fi - Ri) * b - 2 * fy * (l^2 - d^2)
```

This Equation provides the maximum tractive effort based on shear strength and contact area:

```
Fmax = A * tmax = A * (c + p * tan(phi))
```

This Equation calculates the total tractive effort considering track slip and soil shear stiffness:

```
F = Fmax * [1 - (k / (2l * |i|)) * (1 - e^(-2l * |i| / k))] * sign(i)
```

This Equation defines the longitudinal resistive force based on friction coefficient and vehicle weight:

```
R = mu_x * W
```

**Kinematic Model**

```
x' = (r/2) * [w_o * (1 - i_i) + w_i * (1 - i_o)]

y' = -x' * tan(alpha) = -x' * sigma

psi' = (r/2b) * [w_o * (1 - i_o) - w_i * (1 - i_o)]
```

The inner and outer track slips, i_i and i_o:

```
i_i = V_ji / (r * w_i)

i_o = V_jo / (r * w_o)
```

The longitudinal velocities of track sliding with respect to the terrain V_ji and V_jo:

```
V_ji = x' - b * psi' - r * w_i

V_jo = x' + b * psi' - r * w_o
```

**My defined Inputs and Outputs:**

Kinematic Model Inputs: Angular speeds of inside and outside tracks (w_i, w_o)

Kinematic Model Outputs: Inner and outer track slips (i_o, i_i)

Dynamic Model Inputs: Inner and outer track slips (i_o, i_i)

Dynamic Model Outputs: Accelerations (x'', y'')

I appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Dear Portofrei, welcome to Stack Overflow! As you have mentioned about a paper, it is advisable to cite, or provide a link to it. Also, you can add some information about what you have tried, that makes it easier for folks to solve your problem. You can also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)